# Any way to dispatch a closure in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, queue, closures, dispatch

In laravel 4, I could push a closure onto the queue with `queue::push(function...)`, but this no longer works in laravel 5. Instead, it appears that I have to make a custom Job class for every function that I want to push onto the queue.

Since the functions I want to be pushing are only a couple of lines long, and are only ever used in exactly one place, it really seems like a waste of time and space to be writing up a full class for every case.

The best "solutions" I can currently think of, are to either have a helper function that uses PHP's reflection methods to dynamically generate a new class when called, or to have generic job that accepts a closure as parameter, i.e. `dispatch(new ClosureJob(function(){...}));`

These seem less than ideal to me. Is there another way to do this? Or am I going to have to implement one of these?

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Comment: @GGGforce Custom job for each function. I've got about 30 of them now. Just because it's less hassle than trying to do something clever.

Comment: I see. Checkout my answer below, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 8):

As of Laravel v5.7 you can queue an closure like this:

```php
$podcast = App\Podcast::find(1);

dispatch(function () use ($podcast) {
    $podcast->publish();
});
```

Docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#queueing-closures

However it is strongly recommended to use a dedicated job class to improve your code quality and for the sake of a better maintenance of your application. Think of you want to check what tasks are left in queue, or want to control on which queue/connection the particular code should run at.

Therefore you need a dedicated job class:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#creating-jobs

I'd say that writing a dedicated class is pretty much the Laravel standard and this is what you should align to.

Answer (score 2):

I've accomplished this by relying on the [OpisClosure](http://www.opis.io/closure/3.x/index) library. Extend the class as so:

```
class QueueableClosure extends SerializableClosure
{
    public function handle() {
        call_user_func_array($this->closure, func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Queue::push(new QueueableClosure(function(){
    Log::debug("this is the QueueableClosure in action.");
}));
```

**N.B.** See the comment below from @Quezler about possible limitations!

Comment: I noticed the question also has a laravel tag, some parts of it are not entirely compatible with the `opis/closure` library, see https://github.com/opis/closure/issues/15

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#queueing-closures says:

> You may also push a Closure onto the queue. This is very convenient for quick, simple tasks that need to be queued:
>
> Pushing A Closure Onto The Queue

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($id)
{
    Account::delete($id);

    $job->delete();
});
```

However, **my guess is that you're using Laravel 5.3+**, because https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0 says:

> Queueing Closures is no longer supported. If you are queueing a Closure in your application, you should convert the Closure to a class and queue an instance of the class.